# C чего начать?

Tags: asp.net, работа, c#, java

Здравствуйте!

У меня возник небольшой вопрос. Решил "открыть своё дело", собрал команду разработчиков. Специализируемся на создании сайтов на ASP.NET и Java.

Так вот: с чего нам начать? Скоро мы регистрируемся официально, поэтому хотелось бы найти  заказчиков, чтобы работать над более-менее серьёзными проектами. Опыта у нас особого нет, но есть сайт, отлично работающий с неплохим дизайном, который можем предъявить заказчику и сказать: "Ну вот смотрите - хороший сайт, отлично работает, без лагов и с хорошими отзывами пользователей". Сайт действительно хороший :)

Т.е. как всегда самое сложное - это начать. Где найти клиентов? И как заявить вообще о нас? Поделитесь своим опытом, хешкодовцы!

**UPD:** Больше относится к ответу [[@Modus](/users/285/modus)](/users/285/modus):

Каждый из нас уже много работал сам, каждый неплох в "своём деле": я в ASP.NET и Java, другой - в вёрстке, третий - в тестировании. Опыта как команды у нас - один проект. Скоро я доделываю сайт одного заказчика (из Минска, Беларусь) и хотим "объединить наши усилия" и начать **серьёзно** работать вместе. Один **серьёзный** потенциальный клиент, которому я предложил услуги для работы над **серьёзным** проектом, сказал, что не может заключать договор с теми, кто не зареген официально. Поэтому мы и решили зарегатся, а не "болтаться" как фрилансеры.

Но это только один заказчик. Хотелось бы просто узнать как правильно начинать и чтобы кто-то, у кого есть опыт, поделился им.

Жаль, конечно, что этот вопрос приняли так **"в кулаки"**.

Comment: >Сайт действительно хороший :)

ну так ссылку бы дали

Comment: free-lance зачем создан? hh , хатим и прочие сервисы. Если хватило денег официально зарегистрироваться , то и на лапу дать этим сервисам чтобы в топ положили проблем не будет...

Comment: @Spectre, Вы как потенциальный заказчик спрашиваете?)

Потому что иначе это будет выглядеть как реклама, что, как я знаю, в вопросах на Хэшкоде не приветствуется.

Comment: @BoranOnHashCode, А что, так все компании начинают?

P.S. Мы сами по себе на фрилансе работали.

Comment: @megacoder, там может мы глянем на сайт и сказу скажет, что бы бы хтмл сначала подучили и цсс, а потом уже на фрилансе позорились... а может наоборот, офигеем от увиденного и сами вас наймем?)

Answer (score 7):

Видимо, человеку не вложили в голову важнейшую заповедь любого бизнеса: бизнес - это, прежде всего, товар или услуга, а уже потом - организация. Если у человека есть проработанная идея своего бизнеса, таких вопросов возникать не будет.

Это как в анекдоте:

начинающий композитор: как писать симфонии?

Моцарт: вам ещё рано писать симфонии.

начинающий композитор: но ведь вы свою первую симфонию написали в 5 лет!

Моцарт: да, но я ни у кого не спрашивал, как их писать!

Answer (score 6):

Я бы сделал (и делал) ровно наоборот:

1. Есть заказчик с баблосами, который уже окучен
2. Под бабки набираем прогеров/дизигнеров/переводчиков и проч.
3. Если необходимо юридически легализуемся
4. Делаем заказ - пилим бабки

А вот набрать прогеров и бегать искать заказчиков мне кажется дело дохлое.

Допускаю, что этап когда *есть заказчик - пилим бабки* уже пройден. Тогда другое дело, но если этого этапа не было - дело швах.

Answer (score 2):

1. Берете кредит
2. Нанимаете менеджеров по продажам
3. Теперь это их головная боль
4. Кодите, наслаждаетесь жизнью =)

Comment: Теперь это их головная боль - ахахахах :)

Comment: @voiddev, а где же PROFIT?

Comment: Так не работает - уже проверено. Через пару лет придут суровые пацаны которым банк продал ваш кредит и засунут паяльник в анальное отверствие ибо без догляду манагеры и кодеры вмиг растащат весь кредит и все закончится очень быстро. Надо пахать как вол не спать ночами, трахать во все дыры кодеров, манагеров и проч. народ тогда на выходе появится профит - может быть.

Comment: Золотые слова. :)

Answer (score 2):

Поиск по теме [недавней](http://www.weblancer.net/vacancies/47330.html) заявки (хоть она и закрыта уже, я к тому что есть такие вакансии, нужно искать). Еще [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/post/52297/) для ознакомления.

Answer (score 0):

Поработайте в рекламном агентстве годика 3-4 хотя бы, и все станет ясно:)

У многих после первого года работы возникает иллюзия что все прохавал уже(вы мне именно такого персонажа напоминаете, и увы я и сам таким был) а фиг там, и слава богу если не дошло до кредита :)))